# 'Touchend' event of the parent do not fire if remove touched child element on touchstart

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, events, touch

There is a parent div that described on touchstart and touchend event. It has a children that fully cover parent. On touchstart i remove the children and add other one. In this case touchend event will not be fired.
The same mouse events (mousedonw/mouseup) are working good in this case.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3bUq/26/) is the jsfiddle.

I can't use mouse events, because on devices (iPad, Android) mousedown event actually calls not when user begin touch an element but right before mouseup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like i found the solution. I need to combined subscribe: touchstart and mouseup events.

http://jsfiddle.net/e3bUq/27/